# How to get images dynamically From wordpress to image slide?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a site which I am converting to wordpress site,as I am new to wordpress I am not able get images dynamically from wordpress for bootstrap image carousel

this is my code using`<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>`

but i need posts: which goes something like this:

```
 <?php 
                        query_posts(array('category_name' => 'social', 'posts_per_page' => 5));
                        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post() 

                    ?>

<li><?php the_post_thumbnail('social'); ?></li>

<?php endwhile;  endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And here is my code for image slide

```
     <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 topmargin">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

 <?php 
   $qArgs = array(
    'category_name' => 'mainslide',
    'posts_per_page' => '5'
   );

  $newQuery = new WP_Query($qArgs); ?>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <?php if($newQuery->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while($newQuery->have_posts()) : $newQuery->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="item">

                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full'); ?>

      </div>
       <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php endif; ?>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

here is the screen shot

[image: This is the error i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use `wp_Query` instead `query_posts`, for better understanding [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Now, try this:

```
<?php 
   $qArgs = array(
    'category_name' => 'social',
    'posts_per_page' => '5'
   );

  $newQuery = new WP_Query($qArgs); ?>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php if($newQuery->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while($newQuery->have_posts()) : $newQuery->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="item">

                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full'); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: sorry i am stuck with a same problem

Comment: Why? did you try tho code? can you post your the entire code?

Comment: I have edited a question please check it out , would great if you help me out.

Comment: Can you describe the problem with the edited code?, not showed images??

Comment: it is showing error in <div class="item active">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?> in this part of code it says syntax error (i have inserted the image in the question), please check it out

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code, please copy and paste again

Comment: sorry , now i dont have error but images are not getting fetched from the mentioned category and can i know what does this <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full'); ?> , **$post->ID**, 'full' mean?

Comment: Hi, are you sure you have added the post thumbnail right? `full` means the size, you can choose between `thumbnail`, `medium`, `full`.

Comment: ye i did, i have updated the questions, please check